# How to upload file from https direct link to ftp server directly using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, curl

I have a `main server` for computing with a Laravel backend. and a `storage server` for storing the files with unlimited storage and network traffic.

I have recording videos from Zoom, and I want to save them on my storage server.

I mounted the FTP server as a disk in my `Laravel` application using [Laravel Disks](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#ftp-driver-configuration) .
Now I want to upload the zoom recording from Zoom cloud to my external server directly, **Without using temporary storage on my main server**

Something like that:

```
$zoom_stream = Storage::disk('zoom-cloud')->readStream('recording-file.mp4');
Storage::disk('ftp')->writeStream('recording-file.mp4', $zoom_stream);
```

I tried the following, but it not works

```
$zoom_stream = fopen("https://us02web.zoom.us/rec/webhook_download/recording-file.mp4" , 'r+');
Storage::disk('ftp')->writeStream('recording-file.mp4', $zoom_stream);
fclose($zoom_stream);
```

Can anyone suggest a solution? Even if I have to use SSH on my main server to run some Ubuntu tools.

Answer (score 0):

When the allow_url_fopen directive is enabled, you can write scripts that open remote files as if they are local files. For example, you can use the file_get_contents function to retrieve the contents of a web page.

To enable this functionality, use a text editor to modify the `allow_url_fopen` directive in the `php.ini` file as follows:

```
allow_url_fopen = on
```

To disable this functionality, modify the allow_url_fopen directive in the php.ini file as follows:

```
allow_url_fopen = off
```